# CIFaceFeature points incorrect

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, face-detection

this is just some pretty standard code I have tried. What I am trying to do is place two eyeballs and a mouth on a very stable portrait image. Here is what I have tried:

```
 CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage: [tim.image CGImage]];

CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey: CIDetectorAccuracy]];

NSArray *feats = [detector featuresInImage: image];

for (CIFaceFeature *faceFeature in feats) {

    if (faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition) {

        eyeLeft.center = faceFeature.leftEyePosition;
    }

    if (faceFeature.hasRightEyePosition) {

        eyeRight.center = faceFeature.rightEyePosition;
    }

    if (faceFeature.hasMouthPosition) {

        moth.center = faceFeature.mouthPosition;
    }
}
```

The problem is my images do translate their center, but to a very awkward position (AKA not the right position)! Although they do appear in a correct distance relation, except mouth is at top. What this means is that there is:

A mouth on top, a few centimeters below there are two eyeballs which are a few centimeters apart. So they are scaled correctly according to the image view, they are just in the wrong plac

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CIImage` and `UIImage` coordinate systems are inverse, so you have to translate the coordinates.
For example:

```
CGPoint ciMmouthCenter = faceFeature.mouthPosition;
CGPoint uiMmouthCenter;
uiMouthCenter.x = tim.image.size.width - ciMouthCenter.x;
uiMouthCenter.y = tim.image.size.height - ciMouthCenter.y;
```

Comment: The x position is fine but the y coordinate is off, the eyes and mouth are too far down

Comment: Opps, sorry for that. I can't test this at the moment (i'm at win computer). Then it should work if you use original y. (i can check my own project later when i get to the mac).

Comment: Ok thanks my solution was to divide tim.image.size.height-ciMouthCenter.y by 2 like the following:             uiMouthCenter.y = (tim.image.size.height - ciMouthCenter.y) / 2;

Answer (score 2):

You should use the 'SquareCam' app from apple.  It places a square in the correct position for any orientation front and rear cameras.  For my app, I just stripped the code out of the 'SquareCam' that determines the 'faceRect.'  For the mouthPosition I interpolated along the faceRect for the percentage of the x value and y value.